# DynamoDB: Count aggregate group by PK

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I understand that this is not possible in DynamoDB.

DynamoDB Streams seem to be an option, but...

My struggle involves being able to create aggregates over a specific period of time. I want to be able to get the top XX in the past 24 hours at any point in time.

Assume I have categories such as Topics (e.g., IoT, AI, AML, etc.). I want to count the top trending topics over a period of time, such as the top 10 trending topics in the past 24 hours or 72 hours. Based on number of posts in these topics.

How can I achieve something like this with DynamoDB?

I use Topic as my PK, and Timestamp#UserId as SK. So each time a user make a post on a topic, a new document is created.. I save some attributes in the document, but that's not relevant here.

Assume:

1. There are thousands of inserts every second (i.e thousands of posts on different topics)
2. Getting the trending topics isn't a real-time requierment. It can be something that gets calculated every 1h or so and posted somewhere else.

Any pointers is appreciated on best approach, and if another stack would make more sense.

Cheers

Comment: Do you have a fixed range of topics? Do you expect more than 1000 writes per second per topic?

Comment: Might be a use case for custom CloudWatch Metrics, populated via DynamoDB Streams [CDC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html), and [CloudWatch Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-metrics-insights-queryexamples.html).

Comment: Having a coudwatch metric for each of hundreds of topics would be wildly expensive, though that would be a very convenient way to get the time windows.

Comment: @erik258 agree that it would be important to model the costs and try to limit the number of custom metrics tracked.

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan Not fixed. Topics can be created by any user any point of time. Kind of like "hashtag" concept in X/Twitter.

Comment: Would something like this be a good implementation?

"Use DDB Streams and an aggregation item with atomic counters. Can be a separate table. Something like:

pk: {Timestamp w/ hourly granularity} counts: Map { IoT: Number AI: Number etc.. }

Aggregations over any period would just be retrieving those hourly items over that period of time and calculating them. Aggressively batch the records coming into the handler of your stream and it should be pretty performant."

Comment: If you can find a way to make it work well with Dynamo (you should add an answer if you do), I don't think it makes much sense to put them behind an event stream.  you're already contacting dynamo to do the topic write; just add another table to your BatchWriteItem for the topic write.  I think the design you propose has a hot partition key if thousands of topics per second are updating the same partition key.

Comment: @erik258 correct. And two more issues would be the limitaiton of the document size (400K) and cost associated as I'll be charged for the full size every time. Still thinking of another solution, and will post the one I eventually implement. But keen to hear more thoughts and arguments from others.

Comment: https://redis.io/docs/data-types/timeseries/quickstart/ This seems like it would serve your purpose but I am not sure if you can use that extension with managed redis in AWS so you might have to host it yourself (redis is pretty easy to host though).  InfluxDB would probably also work.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

Lambda to write to DDB aggregate table (and original table) from same function

Aggregate table has TimestampHour as PK and Country#City#Topic as SK. Attributes: Count (for now)

The Lambda function will find the right doc using the PK and SK, and update count

EventBridge runs every 1h, invoke another Lambda function, which would go through the last 24 hours documents in the aggregate table, and create trending scores (based on sum counts), rank top 10 and descend order (for each country, city and globally). Write results to S3 json files with proper easy strcuture to construct URLs and retrieve trending topic per country, city or global.

S3 has CloudFront caching its content. So the app query that directly. Pretty fast.

S3 has LCM policy that expire objects that aren't updated in the last 24 hours

Seems to do the trick for now, will continue to optimise.